# Could not build wheels for Prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, c++, toolchain, facebook-prophet, pyproject.toml

I am new to python programming and trying my hand on time-series analysis.
I am using Windows-10 with Python 3.11.0 installed (No option to use anaconda due to policy restriction).
Wanted to install Prophet for my analysis however I am getting he attached error.

Please help me understand the error and how to resolve this? [Error Screenshot [System Versions] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6j4D.jpg)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KXqX.jpg)

I am using
Windows-10,
Python-3.11.0 (MSC v1933 64 bit (AMD64) on win32
MingW64 as complier
GCC 11.2.0
G++ 11.2.0

For Info, I cannot use Anaconda(Python).

Do let me know what's the issue here and how to resolve this.

Comment: Prophet wants to download a tool, but it doesn't work cause you are not authorised to access that endpoint (shows through the `403 Forbidden` HTTP response)